# React - trriger a class on component prop change

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have the following code in my React component:

```
if (props.catchData) {
    className = `${className} spinEffect`;
}

<img src={image} className={className}/>
```

While `spinEffect` is a simple CSS3 animation class:

```
.spinEffect {
    -webkit-animation: spin 0.6s 1 linear;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    30% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(80deg);
    }
    60% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-80deg);
    }
    100% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
  }
```

I want to make a 'spin' (re-apply the class) every time the `catchData` prop changes (as soon as it's not null).
Currently, the spin class works for the first time, but re-applying the class won't trigger the animation.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

To make a `spin` everytime `catchData` changes, you need to re-render the component each time. You can implement this using `key` props.

```
<img key={props.catchData} src={image} className={className}/>
```